# How to zoom to make a window take all the space on screen?

Tags: mac, ui

I've got a Finder window and I want to Maximize it. But when I click the Zoom button (green button on the top-left side of the window) while pressing the Option key, it just does a little bit of zooming, it doesn't do what I call "maximize", which is to take the whole screen. Here's a demo:

https://i.imgur.com/nvxKWgF.mp4

Any way to "maximize", the same way we "maximize" on Windows systems?

Comment: I think it’s Cmd or Opt double click on any corner. I have an answer to a similar question on here somewhere but on phone so can’t find it right now.

Comment: @Tetsujin ah yes, it's Option+Click on a corner to take all the space on the screen (without going full screen). I didn't know shortcuts and window management on Mac OS were going to give me so many headaches. I find this OS anything but intuitive. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome. If you delve far enough into it you’ll find it’s hugely controllable, but that makes it tough to remember all the possibilities.

Comment: Try variants of situations in which that double arrow occurs - you can drag, opt/drag to do different things. There's an oft-forgotten variant - Press Cmd *first* & you can act on a window not currently in focus… without it coming to the front. [This works for clicks too, & also into a different app that's not in focus]. This acts like a large extension to being able to scroll any window without first bringing it forward.

Answer (score 3):

Hold the Option key and double-click on any corner of the window. That will do what you want.

When you double-click on an edge of a window it will snap to the edge of the screen. Do that with the corner and the corner snaps to the corner of the screen. Holding option will do it with the current edge or corner and the opposite one. So Option+double clicking any corner will snap that corner and the opposite corner to the corners of the screen, making the window fill the screen without going into Full Screen mode.

Answer (score -1):

When i click the green button, without any modifier keys, it expands the active window to fill the screen, hiding the top menu bar.

If I use Option and click the button it maximises but keeps the top menu visible.

Comment: Yeah that "full screen" behavior is pretty annoying because it 1) hides the top bar 2) makes it impossible to drag the window around and 3) it creates a new Desktop for the window and moves it all the way to the end of desktops, so if you have your desktops arranged a certain way, it will mess things up.

Comment: Opt/green is fine for many things, but it doesn't always fill the entire screen. Only the Opt d/click in a corner guarantees to do that. As for fullscreen… I don't have sufficient polite words to adequately describe what I think of it ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin I never use it either, but I did descrtibe how it worked - downvoter take note, at least what I did was useful...

Comment: Downvoter was me. OP already said they'd tried Opt/green with no joy.

Comment: @Tetsujin so you missed the first line...

Comment: No. I considered it 'not what the OP asked for'. They didn't ask for fullscreen, they asked for maximise.

Comment: @Tetsujin So you did not understand this text as written by the OP : "*which is to take the whole screen" ??

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you further. The OP quite obviously didn't want fullscreen, as they gone so far as to discover the opt/click method & were clearly asking for "an equivalent to Windows maximise" which, if you weren't aware, includes a menu bar. This was further clarified in comments.